# Project with two remote repositories

Tags: git, cakephp, github, repository

I work now with Git and want things pretty straightforward.

I have a bunch of projects that uses CakePHP. I host my repositories in bitbucket.org.

So, I want to push only the project specific code to bitbucket, with the rest of code being managed directly to the CakePHP github repo.

How do I accomplish that?? Two remote repos, merging the differences in the origin->master?

Comment: Well, here we go. I have a CakePHP application. The default layout has app, lib, vendor and plugin folders. I want all related code to CakePHP to belong only and just only, to cakePHP official repo. All my custom views, controllers and models should belong to my own private repo, mixed with CakePHP contents. As for plugins, I already use submodules.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to check out [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html).  A submodule is a reference to a *specific commit* in another git repository.  I can give you more details if you tell me a bit more about your desired repository layout.

Comment: Hi Andrew... Reopening the topic because I'm having problems. I have a  CakePHP mirror on my bitbucket account, which I merge the real repo with my own custom changes. This customized version of CakePHP should be shared with all my projects, thus has its own repo. I'm using a git commit-tree "orphan no-history" commit, but I get errors when I try to push the repo.